# How to map a site from an aliased domain?

Tags: google-workspace

I use the free version of Google Apps (set up before it stopped to be free) to handle the emails and gdrive for two domains: `example1.com` (primary) and `example2.com` (aliased). My account `joe@example1.com` is admin and I add users via the administration concole from that account.

I want to set up a site for my son via Google Sites: `http://www.example2.com`. I have no problem in creating and maping sites in `example1.com` but I do not know how to do the same in `example2.com`.

When looking at my sites list in example1.com I see that the URL is `https://sites.google.com/a/example1.com`. I tried to change this to `https://sites.google.com/a/example2.com` but I get the message

> You are trying to access Google Admin of example2.com but you do not
>   have a valid logged in account for it.
>
> Sign into one of the existing accounts for example2.com
>
> Or, use one of the below logged in users to manage the corresponding
>   enterprise domain.
>
> (.) joe@example1.com

When choosing `Continue` (the only choice) I get to my admin console.

What is the correct way to set up a site on an aliased domain? (I assume that the mapping exercise is the same afterwards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that this is finally impossible. Per "[Limitations with multiple domains](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182081?hl=en)" it looks like that

> You can only create a custom web address mapping for a site at the primary domain.

I would appreciate very much any ideas and will leave the question as unresolved for now.

Comment: Still impossible in 2023 it seems :(